# Using .include(),.where(),.select() for LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query like this:

```
var rrx = (from camp in db.Campus
                     join camproom in db.CampusRooms
                           on camp.Id equals camproom.CampusId
                      where (camproom.CampusId == 1) && (camp.BranchId == 10) && (camproom.Status == 0)
                     select new CampusCampusRoom { CampName = camp.Name, CampusRoomNo = camproom.RoomNo, CampusClassCapacity = camproom.ClassCapacity, CampusExamCapacity = camproom.ExamCapacity  }).ToList();
```

How can I perform this query using `.include()`, `.where()`, `.select()` clauses?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is no "give me the code I need side". Please show the effort you tried already yourself and we are going to help you solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to use filtered projection example. This should provide you with a good example of what you want to do with your query.:

```
var customersWithRecentReservations = 
    from c in context.Contacts.OfType<Customer>()
    where c.FirstName == p_firstName && c.LastName == p_lastName 
    select new {Customer = c, Reservations = c.Reservations.Where(r => r.ReservationDate >= p_reservationDate)};

var customers = customersWithRecentReservations.AsEnumerable().Select(p => p.Customer);
```

Try and adapt this code to your situation or let me know if you need further assistance with it ;)